# Keep only bit of an expression unevaluated for display

Tags: hold

Consider the code

```
h[x_, y_, n_] := x^2 + (y - (x^2)^(1/n))^2
g[u_] := ContourPlot[h[x, y, u] == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 2}, 
  PlotLabel -> StandardForm[h[x, y, u]] == 1]
g[3.1]
```

which gives

[image]

I would like `1/3.1` to be displayed in the `PlotLabel` instead of the evaluated value `0.322581`. I know about `HoldForm` but how do I apply it only to that bit of the expression.

Comment: Why not to simply write it as `PlotLabel -> StandardForm[h[x, y, "3.1"]] == 1`?  In case you do not want to do that since you intend to automate it, you might wrap u by `ToString` as follows: `PlotLabel -> StandardForm[h[x, y, ToString[u]]] == 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just wrap `HoldForm` around `u` in the plot label to prevent the fraction from being evaluated:

```
h[x_, y_, n_] := x^2 + (y - (x^2)^(1/n))^2
g[u_] := ContourPlot[h[x, y, u] == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 2}, 
  PlotLabel -> StandardForm[h[x, y, HoldForm[u]]] == 1]
g[3.1]
```

> > [image]